# What is the art style of games like Zelda BotW or GW2 called?

Tags: terminology

Like everybody right now I am very excited for Zelda Breath of the Wild and I really love the game's style. It really looks like if a storybook with drawings came to life. Is this a particular style in game design one can search for?

I think Guild Wars 2 and I am Setsuna have similar styles also.

Can anybody tell me what that style is called?

Comment: This isn't on-topic here, this site is not for recommendations.

Comment: The main intent of this question was to find out what the animation style is. The fact that I was asking for recommendations as well is just a bonus in case somebody knows any games with that peticular style.

Comment: I don't think that's on-topic either, but you should probably clarify that then.

Comment: Where should I put it then? I thought this was the main gaming stackexchange where anybody can post any question about whatever lays on their heart.

Comment: I removed the off-topic part from your question. The rest is totally on-topic. Btw, [cel shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading) could be the answer to your question.

Comment: Just because it's the gaming SE site doesn't mean you can "post any question about whatever lays on your heart." There are rules for the site that can be found in the site's [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're speaking about cel shading as @pinckerman said in the comments.
More information right [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading).

By the way, Zelda the Wind Waker was already in that style.